# An alternative to tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver( tpu_name) to be used in Sagemaker?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, amazon-sagemaker, tpu

1. task : object_detection
2. environment: AWS sagemaker
3. instance type: 'ml.p2.xlarge' | num_instances = 1
4. Main file to be run: [original](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py)
5. Problematic code segment from the main file:

   ```
       resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(
       FLAGS.tpu_name)
       tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
       tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
       strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
       elif FLAGS.num_workers > 1:
           strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
       else:
           strategy = tf.compat.v2.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
   ```
6. Problem : Can't find the proper value to be given as `tpu_name` argument.
7. My research on the problem:

According to the tensorflow documentation in [tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/cluster_resolver/TPUClusterResolver), it says that this resolver works only on Google Cloud platform.

> This is an implementation of cluster resolvers for the Google Cloud
> TPU service.
>
> TPUClusterResolver supports the following distinct environments:
> Google Compute Engine Google Kubernetes Engine Google internal
>
> It can be passed into tf.distribute.TPUStrategy to support TF2
> training on Cloud TPUs.

But from [this issue in github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39721), I found out that a similar code also works in Azure.

8. My question :

Is there a way I can bypass this resolver and initialize my tpu in **sagemaker** ?

Even better, if I can find a way to insert the name or url of sagemaker gpu to the resolver and initiate it from there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify some confusion here. TPUs are only offered on Google Cloud and the `TPUClusterResolver` implementation queries GCP APIs to get the cluster config for the TPU node. Thus, no you can't use `TPUClusterResolver` with AWS sagemaker, but you should try it out with TPUs on GCP instead or try find some other documentation on Sagemaker's end on how they enable cluster resolving on their end (if they do).